# C#: Getting a list of names from a website?

Tags: c#, html

There is a website (Evite to be exact) that has a list of attendees for an event I created. Is there a way to get a list of the names of people contained in an unordered list? The actual info I'm trying to get here is the "Some Name" text from each list item. The html looks something like this:

```
<ul>

    <li class="group-replies  yes"
         id="button_group_replies_yes">
         <h4 class="guest-list-group ">Yes (75)</h4>
         <div class="arrow"></div>
         <div class="guest-list-panel">


         <ul>

             <li class="host " data-guestid="">
                  <a class="profile-link" href="/profile/public/00B6AAQZXGK5ZYADLKASDKLR5OASKE">
    <div class="avatar small "
        data-letters="AS"
        data-disk="5"
        data-key="00B6AAAWDGK5ZYAD3OEPAHCPASDWWQKE"
        data-size="small"

            href="javascript:void(0);"

        >
        <span class="avatar-badge"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <span class="username">Some Name
              <span class="badge">Host</span>
        </span>
    </div>
                </a>
<div class="profile-hover">
    <div class="divet"></div>
<div class="contents">
    <div class="meta">
        <p class="timestamp">
            <span class="left">Replied 135 days ago</span>
        </p>
        <p class="guests">
            <span class="adults">
                    1 guest
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

I've tried using HTML agility pack, but I wasn't able to efficiently get the list of names without first finding the list, then going through multiple sets of child nodes to finally find what I was looking for. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to see if the page owners provide an API to request the data you are after?  Generally, mining a page for data through it's HTML is very inefficient by nature.

Comment: If you used HtmlAgilityPack and got the data you were looking for then I'd call it a success.

Comment: evite offers an API that allows you to do that. Check this out. https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/endpoints/events/#ebapi-get-events-id-attendees

Comment: @OlivierDeMeulder I might be completely wrong, but evite and Eventbrite aren't the same thing;  that being said, the OP wasn't exactly clear about the service they were using either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way will be using Html Agility Pack which is recommended.

But if you would like to use some other way, what about using regex?

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"test.html"); // Or any way getting your html string
string pattern = "<span class=\"username\">(?<after>[\\w ]+)";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);

for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Username:" + matches[i].Groups["after"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolving this issue I think we need to use the HTML Parser. There are various HTML Parser available.

I used Html Agility Pack.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_parsers